# Вместо ID показать название продукта

Tags: sql

[image: таблица]
[image: результат]

Здравствуйте. Я прописываю такой код:

```
select sklad.date_do, sklad.p_id
from sklad
where cast (date_do as date) <= '25.05.2022'
```

Где мне выдаётся таблица из двух столбиков: в первом даты, а во втором ID продукта.
Как сделать так, что бы вместо ID - выдавало само название продукта, которое храниться в PRODUCT.NAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этой цели следует использовать `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.date_do, p.name
FROM sklad s INNER JOIN product p
ON s.p_id = p.id
WHERE s.date_do <= '25.05.2022'
```

Для краткости можно писать не `INNER JOIN`, а просто `JOIN`.

В приведённом примере также убрано преобразование в предложении `WHERE`, так как неясно, зачем оно нужно: поле `date_do` и так имеет тип `DATE`, судя по приведённой вами схеме.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое